# How to use React-bootstrap Modal with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am using react, react-bootstrap and typescript.  I get the following error:

JSX element type 'Modal' does not have any construct or call signatures.  TS2604

The code is pretty boilerplate from the react-bootstrap website which works if I use javascript:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap';

class InfoModal extends Component{
    state = { show: true }

    render(){
     <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal! 
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues so I hope this helps anyone with the same issue:

1. The import was wrong it should have been: `import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`
2. `onHide={() => { this.handleClose() }}`